# Json Select Child Field C#

Tags: c#, json

```
dynamic js = JObject.Parse(App.payCommand.Value);
Debug.WriteLine((string)js.Value[0].DisplayName);
```

`App.payCommand.Value` is just a string that I'm parsing to a JObject.

I tried extracting the DisplayName as you can see above, but I only get an error when trying to do so.

If I print out the whole json string I get the following result:

```
{

"Type": "SecondScreen",

"Value": ["\"DisplayName\":\"Zingo\",\"BarCode\":\"54352164895\",\"Price\":5,\"Discount\":0}"
  ]

}
```

How do I extract the DisplayName so that, in this case, I only get "Zingo"?

Comment: Is that really your JSON? Because `Value` contains *an array* with the single literal value: `"DisplayName":"Zingo","BarCode":"54352164895","Price":5,"Discount":0}`

Comment: Hmm I think I understand what you mean, but how do I solve it then? Does my above solution work if it would have been a JSON Object? How can I make it a JSON-object so that I can extract the fields afterwards?

Comment: If there was a proper JSON object (i.e. with a nested object there instead of a string), then your expression would have worked. You should fix the source of that JSON so it produces proper JSON.

Comment: Thank you! Can you provide an example of a "proper Json" as an answer? I will accept it as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your json format should be as following:

```
{

"Type": "SecondScreen",

"Value":[{"DisplayName":"Zingo","BarCode":"54352164895","Price":5,"Discount":0 }]

}
```

Then you can get the values as

```
dynamic x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(App.payCommand.Value);
var displayName = x.Value[0].DisplayName;
```